# How to save contact along with address, Organization and categoriesin iphone using phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova

Anyone help me..

var addresses = [4];

```
                    addresses[0] = new ContactAddress('streetAddress','Die Strasse 45',true);
                    addresses[1] = new ContactAddress('locality','Hamburg',true);
                    addresses[2] = new ContactAddress('postalCode','22041',true);
                    addresses[3] = new ContactAddress('country','Deutschland',true);

                    myContact.addresses = addresses;
```

Above is the code i am trying to add contact address to iOS using Phonegap. But the address not added to Addressbook, rest like Name, phonenumbers are updated properly.

Looking forward to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Vinayak.
I got the solution, problem with iOS not phonegap and below is the working code.The type property required for adding contactAddress in iOS addressbook.

```
                    var addresses= [];
                    addresses[0] = new ContactAddress();
                    **addresses[0].type = 'home';**
                    addresses[0].streetAddress = 'yourStreet';
                    addresses[0].locality = 'yourLocality';
                    addresses[0].postalCode = 'yourPostalCode';
                    addresses[0].country = 'yourCountry';
                    myContact.addresses = addresses;
```

Comment: I did not find any difference between your answer and my answer which I posted below for your question.

Comment: YES, But  without  "**addresses[0].type = 'home';**" this property, you will get null exception error.

Answer (score 1):

In PhoneGap, the addresses array contains several addresses, not several address-details.
To add your address, try :

```
addresses[0] = new ContactAddress();
addresses[0].streetAddress = 'yourStreet';
addresses[0].locality = 'yourLocality';
addresses[0].postalCode = 'yourPostalCode';
addresses[0].country = 'yourCountry';
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks... Still its not working could you please elaborate in detail.

Comment: Here is my code    
var currentContact = null;var contactNum = 0;
function createContact() {
results.innerHTML = "";
try {
var myContact = navigator.contacts.create();
var addresses = [];
addresses[] = new ContactAddress() ;
addresses[0].streetAddress = 'yourStreet';
addresses[1].locality = 'yourLocality';
addresses[2].postalCode = 'yourPostalCode';
addresses[3].country = 'yourCountry';
myContact.addresses = addresses[]; 


myContact.save(onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);  }
    catch (err)
    {alert(err);}
}

Comment: Don't increment the position in your addresses array, stay at addresses[0] (as this is one contactAddress, e.g. the home/work address)

Comment: var myContact = navigator.contacts.create();var name = new ContactName();
var addresses[0] = new ContactAddress();
addresses[0].streetAddress = 'yourStreet';
addresses[0].locality = 'yourLocality';
addresses[0].postalCode = 'yourPostalCode';
addresses[0].country = 'yourCountry';
myContact.addresses = addresses; -- No error but view got struck...

Comment: did you forget to initialize addresses?

Comment: I tried this var addresses= new ContactAddress();
addresses.streetAddress = 'yourStreet';
addresses.locality = 'yourLocality';
addresses.postalCode = 'yourPostalCode';
addresses.country = 'yourCountry';
myContact.addresses = addresses;  -- No error but not created address.. i am new to phonegap..advise me

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var addresses = [1];
var address = new ContactAddress();
address.streetAddress='MyAddress';
address.locality='MyLocality';
address.postalCode='MyPostCode';
address.country='MyCountry';
addresses[0] = address;
contact.addresses = addresses;
```